# Does a converted aircraft require recertification? Does it break manufacturer rights?

Tags: aircraft-certification, aircraft-manufacturer, modifications

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMILhFItbSM) is a very interesting video shows how an Airbus A330 is converted from passenger plane to a cargo plane. There are lots of changes or modifications were made to the airplane to fit the new requirement as a cargo airplane, including removing the passenger seats, strengthening the floors, change the windows and the doors, and many more.

So, what I want to know are:

1. Is such that changes require recertification?
2. Is that conversion is not breached manufacturer right which there is stated that only the manufacturer can do repairing, modification, and so on?

Comment: As for 2. if the client has not purchased the plane with a specific maintenance plan, the manufacturer has pretty much no say in whatever the owner wants to do with the plane. The manufacturers type rating for the plane will, of course, become void if anything major is done to the plane.

Comment: #2 is a grammatical mess.  What is the actual question?  Are you saying that the manufacturer DOES have exclusive rights to perform repair and modifications, or asking whether or not they do?  (Because if they do, such a mod would obviously breach this clause, and if they don't, it wouldn't... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this [point](https://youtu.be/pMILhFItbSM?t=950) in the video it says about a the verification of
all the modifications done to a plane would be verified by an independent third party.

Similarly in this website from [Stirling Dynamics](https://www.stirling-dynamics.com/work/aerospace/passenger-to-freighter-conversion-of-an-airbus-a321/), I could find:

> Any changes to the original aircraft require a detailed analysis of
> the proposed changes and the presentation of design evidence to the
> applicable certification authorities for airworthiness clearance.
> The certification basis for this programme has been agreed with the
> FAA under a Supplemental Type Certificate (STC) and will also be
> validated by the European Aviation Safety Agency (EASA) and the
> Civil Aviation Administration of China (CAAC).

Comment: So, A330 and A321, and it is clearly that the modification of the A321 requires recertification of FAA, EASA, CAAC. It is said under the Supplemental Type Certification (STC). So I think, the modification/conversion of the A330 is the same requirement with the A321, it is requires recertification from at least from those three agencies.  So, I may accept your answer as the answering my question.

Comment: @AirCraftLover Note that an STC is not a complete recertification. It is (as the name suggests) only supplementing the existing certification.

Answer (score 1):

Generally *no the aircraft will not need to be re-certified* however the aircraft *will likely need an updated weight and balance*.

Aircraft have their official weight and balance numbers measured as they are currently configured. [If an airframe has its interior pulled out and some reinforcement done to the airframe it will need a new weight and balance drawn up.](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/faa-h-8083-1.pdf) This is true for all aircraft from pulling the back seats out of my [Cherokee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-28_Cherokee) to stripping out a 747 for cargo work.

In terms of the modification, pulling interiors generally does not require getting the manufacturer involved, many service/repair facilities are capable of this job. [There are even third party doors that can be used for the modification which carry full certifications (STC)](https://www.aeronautical-engineers.com/products).

[Some cargo outfitting may also change the way the aircraft is flown as well…](https://omegataupodcast.net/195-flying-the-shuttle-carrier-aircraft/)

Comment: The comment of @jcbge below regarding the A321 is almost the same case, so I think it is clear that require recertification.

Comment: @AirCraft Lover, I think you may be mixing the terms "inspection" with "recertification".  The types of modifications you describe aren't generally done without approval, instead the configuration is preapproved, or certified by an authority.  Once the work is complete it must be inspected to ensure that it conforms to the TC or STC.  I wouldn't necessarily call the inspection process "recertification", but I have heard the it used this way.  (I have also seen "conform" and "conformity" used when the actual action performed is an inspection...)  Not saying you are wrong, just clarifying FWIW.

Comment: @MichaelHall, according to the link provided by jcbge above, there is mentioned that "Any changes to the original aircraft require a detailed analysis of the proposed changes and the presentation of design evidence to the applicable certification authorities for airworthiness clearance". So, it is required recertification. Of course, different level, just recertify those changes.

Comment: @AirCraft Lover, yes, I agree that a configuration change (for the first time) requires certification and a supplemental type certificate.  My point is that subsequent conversions to an already approved STC just need to be inspected to ensure that they comply to the specs.  And that some people may refer to this as "re-certification", but it is really more accurately described as a conformity inspection.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know，conversion programmes can be in the TC or in the STC
if you search for 737TCDS on faa.gov , you can see 737BCF in that document.that means Boeing has a original 737-800 cargo conversion program
other choice is throught STC, third-party stc holders as AEI ,IAI are also certificated to convert 737-800 from passenger to freighter, as for your question 2,I'm sure AEI and IAI have paid Boeing money for stastic support

Comment: Please edit your answer to usesentences and proper punctuation.  As your answer is currently written, it is very hard to read.

Comment: It was Airbus A330.